# Install Adapter in an offline Computer

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04, adapter

I've found a issue with a network adapter, when connected to a USB port it need a driver, but tested this WIRELESS Adapter in another PC with cable net working it successfully installed drivers with this script:
https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu
i need to install the same scripts and adapters in a computer with no cable internet but i dont know how. i need help with this.

Comment: Can you tether your phone?